# Is there a possibility to pass a defined function as a parameter express.post()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code and it works fine. Is there a possibility to pass a defined function as a parameter `express.post()`.

```
const exs = require('express');
const exs_r = exs.Router();

router.post('/click', function(res, res) {
   //Do something
});
```

I want to ask you is there any possibility so i can call a defined function there like below:

```
router.post('/click', def_myfunc(res, res));
<br />
function def_myfunc (res, res)
{
    // do something
}
```

or does this sound more reasonable:

```
router.post('/click', function(res, res) {
   def_myfunc (res, res);
});


function def_myfunc (res, res)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the function *reference* as parameter rather than invoking it

Change:

```
router.post('/click', def_myfunc(res, res));
```

To

```
router.post('/click', def_myfunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
router.post('/click', def_myfunc);

function def_myfunc (req, res)
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
router.post('/click', def_myfunc);

function def_myfunc (res, res)
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo in the parameters (res). It's not

```
router.post('/click', function(res, res) {
  //Do something
});
```

But (req, res)

```
router.post('/click', function(req, res) {
  //Do something
});
```

That being said, as others posted above, just pass the reference of the function as follows:

```
function def_myfunc(req, res) {
  // whatever
}
router.post('/click', def_myfunc);
```